# Question about promoting an smartphone app, where should I ask it?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As the title says, I would like to ask for advice about promoting applications which I develop for Android and other platforms.

I don't really know where should I post this question: Stack Overflow, Economics or another Stack Exchange site?

Comment: http://startups.stackexchange.com/ ? ....see http://startups.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing, to see if those questions are similar to your's.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't participate so no idea of this is correct, but would this fall under the "game industry" category of [GameDev.SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you both, I think that what Shokhet said approaches more to my idea.